# apache adds extra parameters to url

Tags: php, apache, debian

I installed apache2 on my debian 8 server, then I created a file, named 12.html in the apache web root.

```
<html>
<a href="sdf.html?sdf=sdf">sdf</a>
</html>
```

now when I click on **sdf** link, it adds an extra parameter to the url,

```
http://MY_SERVER_ADDRESS/sdf.html?sdf=sdf&1534-D83A_1933715A=51066fe70b253674b08e33752e6dd6b2a3779812
```

as you can see, unknown added key is:

```
1534-D83A_1933715A
```

and it's value is:

```
51066fe70b253674b08e33752e6dd6b2a3779812
```

I searched the net and found out that many sites have this unknown parameter!!

what is it? I really want to remove it.
I tried reinstalling php and apache but the problem still exists.

Comment: are you on shared hosting? which version of apache?

Comment: my apache version is 2.4.10 (Debian). my server is a vps with dedicate resources.

Answer (score 0):

After many many researches, I foudn that the Cyberoam firewall adds this parameter to our urls.
this completely out of our server and depends on firewall configurations.
I changed firewall configurations and problem solved.